# Tensorflow will not install

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip

Trying to install tensorflow but no matter the method an error installing it always shows

I have tried installing the whl and I have installed the virtualenv

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

I get this error:

> Collecting tensorflow   ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies
>   the requirement tensorflow (fro m versions: none) ERROR: No matching
>   distribution found for tensorflow

I would hope that tensorflow would install from any of the methods I have tried but I have gotten an incompatible whl error and the error shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
pip3 install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

I've used this before. Tell me if it works! =)

Answer (score 0):

You may try to install using link in anaconda -

```
https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tensorflow
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem till I figured out that you need python 3.5.2 for tensorflow, could not install it in 3.6